# How do I run robot framework tests based on git commits?

Tags: git, selenium, jenkins, robotframework, git-extensions

We are developing a web application, in which we run robot framework regression tests against. I'd like to be able to run specific robot framework tests based on tags from git so I wouldn't have to run full regression every time.

Currently I use Jenkins to execute windows batch commands. My first job pulls down everything from the repository.

```
cd /d C:\home\(Repository here)
git pull --summary
```

My second job runs the tests I specify, which is full regression currently.

```
robot -P C:\home\(Repository root here) C:\home\(Path to test cases)
```

Is there a way to run specific tests based on certain tags in git? For example running the "Login" tests because someone pushed a commit that had the [Login] tag in their commit message.

Here's an example of a test suite.

FileName = C:\home(Repo)\Regression\Common\Login\LoginTestSuite.txt

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation    Login Test Suite
Suite Setup    Suite Setup
Library    SeleniumLibrary
Force Tags    LoginTests

*** Test Cases ***
User A Login Test
[Documentation]    This is documentation
[Tags]    Requirement A
(Test Steps Here)
```

**Additional Information**

Robot Framework Version: 3.0.4

Application Front End: AngularJS

Application Back End: C#

Comment: are you asking how to tell Jenkins which tests to run, or are you asking how to identify specific tests from your suite are associated with a tag in a commit message?

Comment: What exactly are you asking - how to get the tags in the commits of the last merge; or, how to run specific robotframework tests?

Comment: Sorry if I didn't clarify enough. I'm asking how to identify specific tests from my suite that are associated with a tag in a commit message.

Comment: What is the structure of your tests set - do you use tags? Any other labeling/categorization methodology?

Comment: We use force tags in the tests themselves, along with a file structure. So our file names are structured in association with the app.

Comment: Ok, if I tell you "run all Login test", how will you identify them? What about something more complex, like a functionality ("run all create object X tests", for example)? Add this info to the question, it's crucial so the community can help you.

Comment: A tag in a commit message is exactly the same as the ones you force to the test cases?

Comment: @TodorMinakov I will identify them based on what the name of the tag is. So lets say someone pushed a changed that affected login. Their commit message would be something like. "[Login] Changed some colors on the login screen." Based on the text inside the [] brackets I want to run tests based on that tag. The problem being I don't know how to get that commit message text inside those brackets. Or is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the discussion in the comments, your goal is to run the Robot Framework tests having specific tags; these tags are coming from the git tags in the latest merge (let's call them *"gtags"*, to distinguish the two).

One specifies the cases to be ran based on their tags through the `--include` [command-line option](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#all-command-line-options); so if the gtags include "LoginTests", you'd run only them like this:

```
robot -P C:\home\(Repository root here) --include logintests C:\home\(Path to test cases)
```

If the gtags are more than one, say they are `(LoginTests, LogoutTests)`, you could append more `--include` options:

```
--include logintests --include logouttests
```

Another option is to combine them in a single `include` argument - RF allows that by using the "AND", "OR" & "NOT" [boolean operators](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#tag-patterns) inside the value:

```
--include logintestsORlogouttests
```

With "AND" only the cases having both tags will be picked, "OR" - the cases having either of the tags (sounds like your case), "NOT" negates the follow-up logic. These three control strings are **case-sensitive**.

Naturally, for this scheme to work the gtags must be the same as the ones you've put in the test cases. If not, you'll have to add some logic to map the gtags to the ones in the cases ("Login" -> "logintests").

The tags in RF are normalized - converted to lowercase and all spaces are removed; for RF `"LoginTest" == "Login Test" == "login test" == "logintest"` *(though the usage of whitespace is discouraged - it's too easy to put two in the source, thus assigning two separate tags to the case)*. So whatever casing comes from the gtags, they'll be matched if after normalization the strings are the same.

Comment: Thank you for the help. Very well put together answer.